# Locked out of raspberry pi with static ip

Tags: networking

Maybe the solution is easy and I'm just stupid, but I configured my raspberry pi on my home router (192.168.0.1/24) using ethernet and gave it a static ip of 192.168.0.150. Now I changed places and I'm working with a router with an ip range of 192.168.8.0/24.

Now even if I connect the raspberry pi via ethernet to the router and nmap the network it doesn't show up ? How do I connect to it ? XD

Comment: Have you tried direct-connecting your RPi to your laptop (or whatever) after setting your laptop to a fixed IP of `192.168.0.5` (for example)?

Comment: @Seamus Would write an answer with your solution but just saw your comment. Make it an answer.

Comment: @Ingo: Thanks, but you go ahead please... I'm involved in something else now & don't want to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered one of the drawbacks of static IP.

There is no simple solution if you don't have a monitor and keyboard.

You could mount the SD Card on a Linux machine (which can be a Pi) and edit the file you changed.

If you connect the Pi to a computer via Ethernet it is possible to ssh into it via the IPv6 Link Local address. This may require you to enable ssh if not already set. Then ssh pi@raspberrypi.local

The third option is to connect via a serial console. This needs a suitable dongle and enabling console in cmdline.txt

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to plug in a display and keyboard, boot it up and change the IP from the UI.